# Solving the Klein-Gordon Equation and Enforcing Causality

Tags: fourier-transform, boundary-conditions, causality, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

Perhaps this is too basic a question, but I am running into trouble attempting to solve the Klein-Gordon equation with a simple spherically symmetric source. Consider, for instance
$$
\square \phi = A(r)\sin\omega_0 t\,.
$$
I can solve this equation in two ways. First, I could compute the Green's function, and then integrate over the source (I have no trouble with this method). Second, I could Fourier transform the source, invert the equation, and inverse Fourier transform. This is where I run into trouble.

Let's begin by Fourier transforming
$$
(-\omega^2 + k^2 + m^2)\tilde\phi = \int{\rm d}t r^2{\rm d} r e^{{\rm i}\omega t}j_0(k r)A(r) \sin\omega_0 t.
$$
I define the form-factor $F(k) = \int r^2{\rm d}r j_0(k r) A(r)$. What's left is to compute the time integral, which is simple enough - it's just two $\delta$-functions
$$
(-\omega^2 + k^2 + m^2)\tilde\phi = F(k){\rm i}\pi(\delta(\omega - \omega_0) - \delta(\omega + \omega_0))\,.
$$
So far so good. Now, I would usually enforce causality using the retarded propagator prescription $\omega\to\omega + {\rm i}\epsilon$. However, here the $\delta$-functions seem to leave me with no choice in how to compute the contour integral over $\omega$
$$
\phi = \int\frac{{\rm d}\omega}{2\pi}e^{-{\rm i}\omega t}\int\frac{k^2{\rm d}k j_0(k r)}{2\pi^2}\frac{F(k){\rm i}\pi(\delta(\omega - \omega_0) - \delta(\omega + \omega_0))}{-(\omega + {\rm i}\epsilon)^2 + k^2 + m^2}\,.
$$
Going on to evaluate these integrals, I find standing waves, not traveling waves as the physics demands. So what's going on here? Clearly I'm making a basic mistake!